# How can I make android mediaplayer play sound?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I don't know why it doesn't works, there is no error logged in logcat, but I cannot hear a sound.

```
public static void DeclararSonido(int numero, Context contexto){
    switch(numero){
    case 0:
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(contexto, R.raw.alan);
        break;          
    }
}

public static void TocarPiedra( int posicion, Context contexto){
    DeclararSonido(posicion, contexto);


    mp.start();
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
}
public static void TocarSirena(Context contexto){
    MediaPlayer mp2= MediaPlayer.create(contexto, R.raw.doh);


    mp2.start();
    mp2.stop();
    mp2.release();

}
```

If I erase `mp2.stop();` and `mp2.release();` AND `mp.stop();` and `mp.release();` the app plays the sound, but the file is not released...

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: *"Alomejor es por la extension"*  Los comentarios en español no son de mucha ayuda para nosotros los de habla inglesa. Por favor, sea traducirlos o dejarlos fuera del código.

Comment: Better to edit the original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276652/mediaplayer-no-works-relese-and-stop-error to better suit Stack Overflow standards rather than post almost the same again.

Comment: see, the question is CLOSED for some people, i don't know why

Comment: @CristianCV, Closed questions can be reopened if they are edited to meet SO standards. See the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You certainly do not want to Start and then Stop right away..

The problem is that you are executing these right after each other:

```
mp.start();      // starts playback
mp.stop();       // .. then stops immediately ..
mp.release();
```

You should call start, and then when the sound is done playing, release. You can use the [Completion event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) to hook up a listener and release there:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
       player.release();          
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Mediaplayer.create():**- creates the new **object of mediaplayer** .this object is having music file from raw folder which is to be played when start() method is called

**Mediaplayer.start():-** **starts playing music** if object Mediaplayer is initialized .otherwise gives exception.

**Mediaplayer.stop() :**-**stops** the current **ongoing music** with that object.

**Mediaplayer.release()**:-the music file path is **no longer associated with Mediaplayer object**. so u need to reallocate memory and all. mind it mediaplayer would not be **null** .

go here and see the [**state diagram of mediaplayer**](http://developer.android.com/images/mediaplayer_state_diagram.gif)

Now what you are doing is that **starting the song and directly stopping it** .I would suggest you to **create button** , and when button is pressed stop the mediaplayer.

Other way is already given by **Miky Dinescu that setoncompletelistner.**

so, do as follows

```
public static void DeclararSonido(int numero, Context contexto){
    switch(numero){
    case 0:
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(contexto, R.raw.alan);
        break;          
    }
}

public static void TocarPiedra( int posicion, Context contexto){
    DeclararSonido(posicion, contexto);


    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(){
    public void OnCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    }});
}
public static void TocarSirena(Context contexto){
    MediaPlayer mp2= MediaPlayer.create(contexto, R.raw.doh);

    //Alomejor es por la extension

    mp2.start();
    mp2.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(){
    public void OnCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
    mp2.stop();
    mp2.release();
    }});


}
```